# Heroku Foreman errors on 0.0.0.0:5000

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to debug this issue using Heroku's Foreman app.  My issue is that Foreman is trying to run the process on port 5000 and at ip address 0.0.0.0.  It says there is something using the port but I am not sure how to figure that out as I have nothing else running.  I tried running 'netstat -lnt | grep 5000' with nothing.

```
> foreman start
11:16:45 web.1  | started with pid 17758
11:16:46 web.1  | 2013-12-31 11:16:46 [17758] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
11:16:46 web.1  | 2013-12-31 11:16:46 [17758] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
11:16:46 web.1  | 2013-12-31 11:16:46 [17758] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
11:16:47 web.1  | 2013-12-31 11:16:47 [17758] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
11:16:47 web.1  | 2013-12-31 11:16:47 [17758] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
```

I run the gunicorn command by it's self and it works fine (so I was able to eliminate that as an issue):

```
> gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
2013-12-31 11:25:33 [17853] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-12-31 11:25:33 [17853] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (17853)
2013-12-31 11:25:33 [17853] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-12-31 11:25:33 [17856] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17856
```

I am running this on my Mac (10.8).

Any insight on how to figure this out would be greatly appreciated.

-rb

---

Upon further investigation, I discovered that 0.0.0.0:5000 is used by Bonjour, Apple's network discovery app.  Looking into how to change the port for Foreman next.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured this all out.

Solve is to manually set the port in the env and run foreman that way.

```
export PORT=5001
```

then

```
> foreman start
13:22:23 web.1  | started with pid 18194
13:22:24 web.1  | 2013-12-31 13:22:24 [18194] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
13:22:24 web.1  | 2013-12-31 13:22:24 [18194] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5001 (18194)
13:22:24 web.1  | 2013-12-31 13:22:24 [18194] [INFO] Using worker: sync
13:22:24 web.1  | 2013-12-31 13:22:24 [18197] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18197
```

I imagine this will be an issue for everyone on OSX and hopefully this will save some headaches.

-rb

Comment: I tried doing the same thing but I am still experiencing the errors, any idea what else might be wrong?

Comment: Same here. Tried export PORT=5001 and still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

responding here as this page is the top listing on Google for 'Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)'

The answer at [Virtual env: Connection in use error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375482/virtual-env-connection-in-use-error) worked perfectly for me:

> you can find the id for unicorn to kill it via `ps ax|grep unicorn` and then using the id of the gunicorn instance `kill <id>`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a gunicorn process running to kill and none of the other suggestions worked for me so I tried restarting my Mac (OSX 10.9.2) with the "Reopen  windows when logging back in" checkbox unchecked and after rebooting it started working again.