# Virtual env: Connection in use error

Tags: git, github, virtualenv

I was working on github cloned folder, and created my first ever branch. After switching branches/closing the terminal I went back into my project dir root and ran the usual:

```
  $ source venv/bin/activate
    (venv)$ foreman start
    14:13:42 web.1  | started with pid 5591
    14:13:42 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:42 [5591] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
    14:13:42 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:42 [5591] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
    14:13:42 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:42 [5591] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    14:13:43 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:43 [5591] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
    14:13:43 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:43 [5591] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    14:13:44 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:44 [5591] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
    14:13:44 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:44 [5591] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    14:13:45 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:45 [5591] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
    14:13:45 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:45 [5591] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    14:13:46 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:46 [5591] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
    14:13:46 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:46 [5591] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    14:13:47 web.1  | 2014-04-29 14:13:47 [5591] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
    14:13:47 web.1  | exited with code 1
    14:13:47 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
    SIGTERM received
```

And I am receiving this error, and I can't quite figure out what the issue is. Does it have to do with branching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have an instance of gunicorn running. foreman runs a daemon instance of gunicorn so if you close terminal down it will still run in the background. For this reason you should always Ctrl + C foreman before closing down terminal. There is however a way to kill the server.

Firstly you can find the id for unicorn to kill it via `$ ps ax|grep unicorn` and then using the id of the gunicorn instance `$ kill <id>`

Alternatively you can use `$ pkill gunicorn`